# In Selenium IDE how can you copy and go to a text link on webpage

Tags: dom, xpath, selenium-ide

I have an issue, the website I am testing has an unclickable text url. In manual testing you copy it and paste it in the address bar.

I am using selenium IDE to automate the manual test, however the link text string is not not static.

I have tried to understand the use of DOM elements, however the element that selenium detects is the div block including other unwanted text.

There seems to be a link in the underlying html, but I have no idea how to click it.

The underlying data shows the following, the alphanumeric string in the link changes hence the need to select the string each time to open the webpage.

```
<div id="content">
```

`

```
<!--      messages.jsp    -->
<p>
    <link href="http://sample-sp:80/merci/rss-feed/0000000049eb98640149f5af3fcc001f" title="RSS" type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate"></link>
</p>
<h1></h1>
<br></br>
<h2></h2>
<br></br>



        Currently no FTP file orders on …

<h2></h2>
<br></br>



        Currently no offline orders on s…

<br></br>
<h1></h1>
<br></br>



  http://sample-sp:80/merci/rss-feed/0000000049eb98640149f5af3fcc001f
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in form of using firebug and firepath.

The command "store" the x-path "//div[@id='content']/text()[11]" then opening the page gave the desired effect. Had a small debug issue in that selenium does not recognize a leading fullstop that firepath displays.

storeText  ...   //div[@id='content']/text()[11]  ...    url

open  ...    ${url}  ...